# For loop excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using a lot of java recently and VBA within the excel environment feels difficult to troubleshoot comparitively. I'm trying to create a baisc for if loop and the error is so generic (Run-time error 1004) application-defined or object-defined error that I have no idea what to change. additionally, I'm not so familiar with VB syntax to know where I'm missing something. Code below.

```
Sub Loopcheck()

Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select


For i = 2 To 100

If Cells(i, 18).Value = "FLAG" Then
x = Range(Cells(i, 18))
y = Range(Cells(i, 18))

Range(x, y).Value = 1

End If

Next i
```

Comment: Where a `r` variable is defined?

Comment: R should be the column. Bad syntax for that?

Comment: you didn't assign any value to r

Comment: Edited for appropriate column ref. Still, obviously, doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `x = Range(Cells(i, 18))`?

Comment: Im not very good at VB. It's fine guys. Gonig to do it manually. It's not really fair for me to ask this question as I haven't done the work on my end to get to the point to ask intelligent questions.

Comment: Is the goal to change the Cell value "FLAG" to the number one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range and Cells are 2 different ways to get the same thing.

I.e. `Range("A1")` = `Cells(1,1)`

the following should work

```
Sub Loopcheck()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select


    For i = 2 To 100

        If Cells(i, 18).Value = "FLAG" Then
            x = Cells(i, 18)
            y = Cells(i, 18)

            Range(x, y).Value = 1

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

However, after fixing that issue, you are likely going to have another issue because it appears that you are assigning x and y values that are not integers. At least that is what it appears since in this line you are testing for text values: `If Cells(i, 18).Value = "FLAG"`.